# Load JS file with html content via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Loading JS file with HTML content to a div via ajax, if I load it multiple times the JS functions inside the test.js file runs multiple times like the content is loaded.

Creating the HTML content with PHP:

```
$html = '
    <script src="js/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div id="form-container" class="p-3">
       <label>Teszt</label>

        <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
            <option value="t1">type 1</option>
            <option value="t2">type 2</option>
        </select>

    </div>
';
```

After the content is created, it sends back to the ajax and adds the content to the div.

Inside the test.js file there is event handlers like:

```
$(document).on("change", '#type', function (event) {
   alert("test");
});
```

I tried to add a .js file version with PHP DateTime, but it's not working.

Comment: Whats in the js/test.js file? Or well "how does the test.js file looks like?"

Comment: @MKougiouris There is event handlers inside it, i was updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, with the multiple ajax load it delegate the event handlers multiple times.

To avoid it, need to remove the event handler before delegate it again.

```
$(document).off("change", '#type');

$(document).on("change", '#type', function (event) {
   alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

```php
<?php

$timestamp = time();

$html = "
    <script src='js/test.js?ver={$timestamp}' charset='utf-8'></script>
    <div id='form-container' class='p-3'>
       <label>Teszt</label>
    </div>
";
```